# Inheriting from a nodejs module (open-graph)

Tags: node.js, inheritance, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to extend the open-graph module in nodejs, so as to override some of the functions. I have been unable to do so. Seeking help in inheriting some functions and overriding others of the below listed class.

Here are the excerpts from open-graph module

```
module.exports = function(url, cb, options){                                   
   exports.getHTML(url, function(err, html){                                  
       if (err) return cb(err);                                               
       cb(null, exports.parse(html, options));                                
    })                                                                         
}

exports.getHTML = function(url, cb){
     ... does something, calls cb
}

exports.parse = function(html, options){
     ... does something
}
```

I want to use the parse function present in this class.

I have written my own getHTML (and constructor that calls it).

Repeat, how do I inherit this class, so as to override getHTML and "the constructor".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
var og = require('open-graph');

og.getHTML = function(url, cb) { // overwrite getHTML
  // your code here
}

og.parse(foo, bar); // calls original parse function
og.getHTML(someurl, yourcallback); // calls your custom function
```